# What are these constants and why do we use them in this equation?

Tags: waves, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

The equation $f(t) = D \sin(\omega t +\phi)$, here the constants are $D$ and $\phi$ and they are added while deriving the given equation from

$$f(t) = A\sin(\omega t) \tag{1} $$

$$f(t) = B\cos (\omega t) \tag{2}$$

Do $D$ and $\phi$ denote any physical quantities or anything? I’m just confused.

In equations $1$ and $2$ does $A$ and $B$ indicate amplitude?

Comment: Please don't edit an existing question replacing it with a completely new one as my answer below is now of no use to anyone who comes across this post in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The superposition of (1) and (2) is the general solution of a second order differential equation with two arbitrary constants $A$ and $B$. The solution may instead be recast in the form involving the two parameters $D$ and $\phi$. So, on mathematical grounds, the number of free constants is the same in both cases and you may derive the relationships between the two sets of constants.

Physically, the $A,B$ and $D$ represent amplitudes as you say and the $\phi$ a phase shift, which exploits the fact that addition of sins and cosines can instead be written simply as a shifted sin, for example, captured by the $\phi$. The constants of course encode the initial conditions relevant to the particular problem at hand.

**Edit** in response to comment:

By '*superposition*' I really just mean that the general solution of a second order differential equation of the form $$\ddot{y} + \omega^2 y = 0, \,\,\,\,\,\text{where}\,\,\,\,\ddot{y} = \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2}$$ is $$y(t) = A\cos (\omega t) + B \sin (\omega t),$$i.e the *summation* of two linearly independent functions, $\sin$ and $\cos$.  'Second' order means the equation contains at most *two* derivatives of the function $y$ with respect to the independent variable $t$, which means the solution must contain *two*  arbitrary constants, in this case labelled by $A$ and $B$.

But one can alternatively write $$A\cos (\omega t) + B \sin (\omega t) = D \sin (\omega t + \phi)$$ using the trigonometric addition formula $\sin(A+B) = \sin A \cos B + \cos A \sin B$ and identify $$\begin{cases} D^2 = A^2 + B^2 \\ \tan \phi = B/A \end{cases}$$

If you are given initial conditions for the physical problem at hand, e.g something like $y(t=0)=y_0$ and $\dot{y}(t=0) = 0$ (corresponding to a spring initially stretched by an amount $y_0$ and released from rest) then $D$ and $\phi$ (or equivalently $A$ and $B$ through the above relations) are determined.

Comment: What does superposition mean? Second order differential equation. I'm really new to all this stuff. I would be very grateful if you could explain it in simpler terms please?

Comment: @JacobP.J I've edited my post, hopefully it is clearer.